# IE 8+ XDomainRequest 'POST' not working with WebAPI

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, xdomainrequest

I have search on googled but no success to achieve the solution

My Code is

```
var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
if (xdr) {
    $.support.cors = true;
    xdr.open(method, svcUrl, true);
    xdr.onload = function () {
        var result = $.parseJSON(xdr.responseText);
        if (result === null || typeof (result) === 'undefined') {
            result = $.parseJSON(
                data.textContent);
        } 
        if ($.isFunction(successCallBackFunction)) {
            successCallBackFunction(result);
        }
    };
    xdr.onerror = function () {
        if ($.isFunction(errorCallBackFunction)) {
            errorCallBackFunction();
        }
    };
    xdr.onprogress = function () {};
    xdr.send(JSON.stringify(params));
}
return xdr;
```

**My Problem is request is hitting my webapi but data is null**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have googled and faced this problem many days, at last I created `AJAX` request on same domain means (`Action in my application`). This action is calling `Web API` means `we can call server to server` and send the response from web api to `ajax`.

Answer (score 0):

`xdr.send($.parseJSON(params))` seems to be wrong - you should not pass js object into send method - you should pass either json string or namevalue collection (like when posting form), specifying correct Content-type Header `(application/json or application/x-www-form-urlencoded)`

Comment: But $.parseJSON(params) will deserialise it to an object, if params is json string do not parse it.

Comment: I see, and what about headers? And does your WebAPI supports json (it should by default).

Comment: WEB API supports json

Comment: So ensure model binding works with body not the query string (any attributes on action parameters at server side) and the Content-type/Content-Length headers are set properly (I don't see you set them at all). Also start fiddler to intercept you reqeusts to ensure it is propertly formed. It's hard to advice anything else :)